# increment single digit (msb) for a given integer

Tags: c++, c

for a given number

```
unsigned int a = 1203;
```

Increment the Most significant decimal digit only so for above sample

```
a = 2203;
```

How can this be achieved?

i started like this

```
for (n=a; n; n/=10){ b = n%10;}
```

This gives msb then increment b++;

But failed to put back the whole number?

Is there any alternative like a&0xf000 which gives msb but the integer can be anything in a range of 0 - INT_MAX?

Comment: integer overflow is implementation dependent, you knows about this na??

Comment: That's a very non-standard definition of MSB, usually it means the Most Significant Bit (or Byte), and that's definitely not what you're describing.

Comment: You mean "most significant decimal digit", presumably.  And basically you figure out how many digits and add 1/10/100/1000/whatever based on that length.  Several ways to do this, depending on how fancy you want to get.

Comment: to clarify instead of MSB it should be most significant digit and yes overflow can happen but ignore it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were actually pretty close.

```
int x = 1;
for (n=a; n; n/=10) {
    x *= 10;
} 
a += x;
```

Comment: Thanks, minor correction either we have to reduce the x by 10 or the loop should be one less   
check here http://ideone.com/PL6TG2

Comment: @czarx - Yeah, I didn't work it through carefully.  I figured you were close enough that you could figure out the rest, if it wasn't quite right.

Answer (score 1):

A variant without the extra variable *n*:

```
int x = 1;
while (x <= a/10) x *= 10;
a += x;
```

(Edit) This should be slightly faster, as it removes *d* divisions in the comparing loop and adds only a single one after it:

```
int x = 1;
while (x <= a) x *= 10;
x /= 10;
a += x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to figure out how many digits you have (typically by dividing by 10 - or whatever the base is) - and when you have the highest digit, add 1 to it, and re-assemble the number (or figure out what number is 1 more to the highest digit, but you still need to know how many digits you have).